# how do I update innerHTML in a for loop using a while loop?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Thought I had this in the bag...guess I was wrong:

Expected behavior - page loads, then for each element in the array it updates my innerHTML value using setTimeout

Observed behavior - On my hosting it seems to update the value just one time, then it breaks my css before becoming unresponsive. I threw in an alert to see if it's ever running on jsFiddle and it appears to **not** be running so there's also that

The markup:

```
<button type="button" id="ctaButton" class="cta btn btn-lg btn-success pulsate" data-keyboard="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactUs">Get Started Today</button>
```

The JS:

```
$(warmup());

function warmup(){
    //sanity check
confirm("working???");
    setTimeout(changeCTAtext, 3000);
}



 function changeCTAtext(){

    var ctaList = [ 'Complementary Quotes', 'Book Your Consultation', 'Get Started Today' ];
    var myField = document.getElementById("ctaButton");

    while (true){
        for (var i = 0; i<ctaList.length, i++;){
    setTimeout('myField.innerHTML = ctaList[i];', 1000);
        };
    };
};
```

and here is the *mandatory* [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpf8jtg6/12/) as usually requested.

Comment: `setTimeout("changeCTAtext()", 3000);` should be `setTimeout(changeCTAtext, 3000);` to prevent EVAL-ing the string.

Comment: alright I'll fix that accordingly...do you think it's happening because I have to wrap  `'myField.innerHTML = ctaList[i];'` in an anonymous function?

Comment: the while loop is stacking massive amounts of timers... this is probably a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to set synchronous multiple timeouts inside a loop.
**Use only a single `setInterval` or recall a function than has a single `setTimeout`**

### You could easily do this using `setInterval()`

If you want to make your code simpler (without the iterations counter) you could just manipulate the Array like:

```js
jQuery(function($){

  var $btn = $("#ctaButton"),
      ctaList = ['Get Started Today', 'Complementary Quotes', 'Book Your Consultation'];
  
  function changeCTAtext(){
    ctaList.push( ctaList.shift() ); // manipulate
    $btn.html( ctaList[0] );         // and use always the [0]th index
  };

  setInterval(changeCTAtext, 1000); // Start

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="ctaButton">Get Started Today</button>
```

### usign a `c` counter and loop using `++c % array.length`

```js
jQuery(function($){

  var $btn = $("#ctaButton"),
      ctaList = ['Get Started Today', 'Complementary Quotes', 'Book Your Consultation'],
      tot = ctaList.length,
      c = 0; // iterations counter
  
  function changeCTAtext(){
    $btn.html( ctaList[++c%tot] );
  };

  setInterval(changeCTAtext, 1000); // Start

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="ctaButton">Get Started Today</button>
```

Using `setTimeout()` it's like this:

```js
jQuery(function($){

  var $btn = $("#ctaButton"),
      ctaList = ['Get Started Today', 'Complementary Quotes', 'Book Your Consultation'],
      tot = ctaList.length,
      c = 0; // iterations counter
  
  function changeCTAtext(){
    $btn.html( ctaList[c++%tot] );
    setTimeout(changeCTAtext, 1000); // ...and repeat every NNNms
  };

  changeCTAtext(); // Start

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="ctaButton">Get Started Today</button>
```

Comment: is the $ in front of `$btn` required because its assigned to a jquery selector?

Comment: @Frankenmint yes but it's not required. It's just a useful way to know that a variable is assigned to a jQuery object. Let's say you're looking at someone's code, when you see i.e: `$value` you'll know immediately that it's not a string or a number but a reference to a DOM element.

Comment: okay so it's more of a styling preference and has no impact on code  execution?

Comment: @Frankenmint yes and a totally useful one. I also use it all the time and like really much seeing developers use it too. `$` is just a character as `_` or `aZ` allowed in variable names. You coul've used `btn` aswell. But following the above logic it's good to be consistent troughout the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

I found two mistakes in your code:

1. `setTimeout` first param should be a function. So it should be written as follows

`setTimeout(changeCTAtext, 3000);`

and

```
while (true){
    for (var i = 0; i < ctaList.length; i++){
setTimeout(function(){myField.innerHTML = ctaList[i]}, 1000);
    };
};
```

2. When you use the iterated index of a for loop inside a timeout, when the timeout ends the index has already changed. Thus you need to bind the index in each iteration. There are several fixes for this, one of them is placing the timeout inside an IIFE with the index as closure:

.

```
for (var i=0; i < ctaList.length; i++) {
  (setTimeout(function(i) {myField.innerHTML = ctaList[i]}, 1000)(i);
}
```